# React component not displaying fetched data due to incorrect URL construction (404 Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm working on a React component to fetch data from a Django REST Framework API using Axios. However, the component isn't displaying the fetched data, and I'm encountering a 404 Not Found error in the network tab.

Post.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Post({ postId }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
console.log(postId)
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/posts/${postId}`;
      console.log('Constructed URL:', url);
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/posts/${postId}`); 
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
        console.error('Axios request error:', error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchPost();
  }, [postId]);


  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>Loading post...</p>
      ) : error ? (
        <p>Error fetching post: {error.message}</p>
      ) : (
        <article>
          <h2>{data.title}</h2>
          <p>{data.content}</p>
          <p>Author: {data.author.username}</p> // Assuming author data is included
          <p>Categories: {data.categories.map((category) => category.name).join(', ')}</p> // Assuming categories data
          <p>Tags: {data.tags.map((tag) => tag.name).join(', ')}</p> // Assuming tags data
          {/* Additional elements for comments, etc. */}
        </article>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

API Response (when accessed directly):

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 1,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test"
        }
    ],
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Post1",
    "content": "asdijfoiajfoajsfopajsfpoasjfopajdfpoaodjfpadfiapoidfjapdfoajsdfpoaispdfajsdfopasfiojapdfjaopssdfjpajdfoiajpsfaf",
    "created_at": "2024-01-04T15:57:20.472070Z",
    "author": 1
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Posts from './components/Posts/Posts';
import Post from './components/Post/Post';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Global.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Posts />} />
          <Route path="/posts/:postId" element={<Post />} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Troubleshooting Steps:

Verified API Response: The API endpoint returns the expected data structure when accessed directly.
Checked Network Requests:
The request URL in the network tab is http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/posts/undefined.
This is causing a 404 Not Found error.
Inspected State Values: The data state is not being populated due to the failed request.

Additional Information:

React version: react@18.2.0
Axios version: "axios": "^1.6.4",
Django REST Framework version: djangorestframework==3.14.0
Browser and version: Chrome Versión 120.0.6099.129
What could be causing the incorrect URL construction, and how can I ensure the correct postId is passed to the component?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your code in your Post component is using the prop `postId` instead of the path parameter `:postId`. When you create your Post component in the `element` prop of the route component, you don't set the `postId` as prop. Thats why it is always `undefined` and your code does not work like expected. At this point you mix up the concept of react props and how to access path parameters with `react-router-dom`.

If you want to access path parameters like your `:postId` in your functional react component than you can use the `useParams` hook of `react-router-dom`.
This hook gives you access to all route parameters.

**Solution:**

App

```
...
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Posts />} />
          // you define a path parameter :postId, which can get accessed in your Post component via useParams hook
          <Route path="/posts/:postId" element={<Post />} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Post

```
...
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
// removed prop postId because it is not needed
function Post() {
  // get path param
  const { postId } = useParams()
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
console.log(postId)
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/posts/${postId}`;
      console.log('Constructed URL:', url);
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/posts/${postId}`); // Corrected URL
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
        console.error('Axios request error:', error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchPost();
  }, [postId]);


  return (...);
}

export default Post;
```